# Swift: slow build times when changing struct code

Tags: swift, xcode, compilation

**tl;dr**

Applying a code change to a commonly used `struct` causes very slow build times. Can this be avoided?

---

I have a rather large Swift project (Xcode 9.2) where I use a `struct` to hold all styling information (colors, spacings, etc.) used by in the app, something like:

```
struct Style {
  var iconColor: UIColor = .darkGray
  var lightTextColor: UIColor = .gray
  // ... and many more properties ...

  static var defaultStyle: Style { 
    return Style() 
  }

  static var fancyStyle: Style {
    var style = Style()
    // ... override style props for more fancyness ...
    return style
  }
}
```

Every view controller (there are about 30 VCs in the project, all created in code -- no storyboards used) has a `Style` instance and uses it when rendering its UI:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  var style = Style.defaultStyle // can be overridden by creator of the VC
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myLabel.textColor = style.lightTextColor
  }
}
```

This works pretty nicely and allows to change settings in one place only, without polluting the namespace with global constants.

However, I noticed that when changing a property's default value inside the `struct` the compile time rises dramatically, Xcode basically performs a full rebuild. E.g. changing the above definition of `Style.lightTextColor` to `var lightTextColor: UIColor = .green` leads to a build time comparable to a full rebuild of the project. If, however, I change the value directly where it is used; e.g. in the view controller: `myLabel.textColor = .green`, the project builds very quickly.

Is there a solution for this, preferably by configuring the compiler to do ... less work in this case?